# background image width and height some problems. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create background of content image according to window height and width for some reasons it is not working. Could you help me where i  make mistake? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95Bvp/2/)

```
 <div class='content'>
        <p>Hi there</p>
    </div>

var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).on('click', function(){
    alert(height);
})
var content = $('.content');
content.css({
    'width' : width + 'px'
    'height' : height + 'px'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed one comma over here,

```
content.css({
    'width' : width + 'px',
//------------------------^
    'height' : height + 'px'
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/95Bvp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).on('click', function(){
    alert(height);
})
var content = $('.content');
content.css({
    'width' : width + 'px',
    'height' : height + 'px'
});
```

**If something doesn't work in JavaScript, first to do is to press F12 and check console output.**